# Как объединить несколько столбцов добавлением снизу?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть такой фрейм данных:

```
    Time    2007-01-01  2007-01-02  2007-01-03  2007-01-04  2007-01-05  2007-01-07  2007-01-08  2007-01-09
    Close   1.32120     1.32724     1.31690     1.30860     1.29995     1.30039     1.30356     1.29919 
    High    1.32176     1.32951     1.32903     1.31783     1.31029     1.30141     1.30389     1.30517
    Low     1.31650     1.32101     1.31461     1.30704     1.29804     1.30006     1.29722     1.29855
    Open    1.31908     1.32137     1.32702     1.31689     1.30866     1.30097     1.30055     1.30350
```

Всего более 4000 столбцов. Мне нужно нарезать длинную таблицу и получить такого вида:

```
id  Time    01          02          03          04  
1   Close   1.32120     1.32724     1.31690     1.30860      
    High    1.32176     1.32951     1.32903     1.31783     
    Low     1.31650     1.32101     1.31461     1.30704     
    Open    1.31908     1.32137     1.32702     1.31689     
2   Close   1.29995     1.30039     1.30356     1.29919
    High    1.31029     1.30141     1.30389     1.30517
    Low     1.29804     1.30006     1.29722     1.29855
    Open    1.30866     1.30097     1.30055     1.30350
```

И так далее вниз. Как это возможно с помощью?

Исходный фрейм данных:

```
    Time        Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
0   2007-01-01  1.31908 1.32176 1.31650 1.32120 1995282
1   2007-01-02  1.32137 1.32951 1.32101 1.32724 2009661
2   2007-01-03  1.32702 1.32903 1.31461 1.31690 2016603
3   2007-01-04  1.31689 1.31783 1.30704 1.30860 2007990
4   2007-01-05  1.30866 1.31029 1.29804 1.29995 1916561
5   2007-01-07  1.30097 1.30141 1.30006 1.30039 96987
6   2007-01-08  1.30055 1.30389 1.29722 1.30356 2008364
7   2007-01-09  1.30350 1.30517 1.29855 1.29919 2000772
8   2007-01-10  1.29921 1.30002 1.29261 1.29347 2024197
9   2007-01-11  1.29345 1.30124 1.28804 1.28910 2006027
```

Comment: Как вы получили данный DataFrame? Похоже это результат `PIVOT` - если это так, то проще работать с исходным DataFrame, __до того__ как вы сделали `PIVOT`

Comment: Да, это результат pivot_table. А как из исходного можно получить нужный мне результат?

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе пример исходных данных?

Comment: Смотрите, df.head(10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .drop(columns=["Time", "Volume"])
       .assign(x=(np.arange(len(df))%4)+1, y=np.arange(len(df))//4)
       .set_index(["x", "y"], append=True)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(name="val")
       .pivot_table(index=["y", "level_3"], columns="x", values="val")
       .rename_axis([None, None])
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

где `df` - исходный DataFrame (до операции `pivot`)

результат:

```
In [66]: res
Out[66]:
             1      2      3      4
0 Close 1.3212 1.3272 1.3169 1.3086
  High  1.3218 1.3295 1.3290 1.3178
  Low   1.3165 1.3210 1.3146 1.3070
  Open  1.3191 1.3214 1.3270 1.3169
1 Close 1.2999 1.3004 1.3036 1.2992
  High  1.3103 1.3014 1.3039 1.3052
  Low   1.2980 1.3001 1.2972 1.2986
  Open  1.3087 1.3010 1.3006 1.3035
2 Close 1.2935 1.2891    nan    nan
  High  1.3000 1.3012    nan    nan
  Low   1.2926 1.2880    nan    nan
  Open  1.2992 1.2934    nan    nan
```

Comment: Да, всё работает, спасибо. У меня ещё вопрос: если нужно будет сделать со смещением по дням, то есть вторая группа строк начинается с 2007-01-02, третья - с 2007-01-03 и т.д. как это можно будет реализовать?

Comment: @Сергей _У меня ещё вопрос_, просто [задайте его](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).